# How to read the real url of a sub-domain in php?

Tags: php, url, subdomain

Ok, say I have a sub-domain set up as:  `mysubname.mysite.net`, which, in actuality, takes me to the following URL:  `http://mysite.net/aName/bName/cName/eName`

How can I get the `http://mysite.net/aName/bName/cName/eName` path, in PHP, which is the real path relative to my site?

Is this possible? Do I have to use a .htaccess file to accomplish this?  I just need to store this REAL Path in a php variable.  I don't want to change the url to the new path, just need to know the url of the actual REAL, longer, PATH!

For Example, I am wanting to use a Flash MP3 Player on my site... it works on the long URL:  [ACTUAL PATH of where Sub-Domain points to](http://dream-portal.net/sub-domains/flashmp3player/script.html)

Although, if you go to the SUB-DOMAIN, it does not play the mp3 files:  [HERE](http://mp3player.dream-portal.net/script.html)

I'm thinking it has to do with this code, that is in PHP, which is needed for the Flash Player to work:

```
$path= $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] .$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$path=dirname($path);

$file='http://'.$path.'/'.$file;
```

Any Ideas?  I can post up more code it you think it would help...  Let me know.

Comment: when the server sends the user to the long url, does it do a redirect to that long url, or does it just give that long url's content without an HTTP redirect?

Comment: it just gives that long url's content without an HTTP redirect for now...  So you can access the site with either the sub-domain or the long url... both work.

Answer (score 1):

PHP has a global variable that may help you with this.  I think that what you want is `HTTP_REFERER`.  The best thing to do would be to `print_r` the PHP `$_SERVER` variable at the top of the page `http://mysite.net/aName/bName/cName/eName` and then use the variable that contains the URL that you want.

So at the top of the page paste this code:

`<pre>
print_r($_SERVER);
</pre>`

[PHP Manual $_SERVER documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

Come to think of it `REQUEST_URI` might be what you want.  Again, the best thing would be to print out `$_SERVER` and see what variable has what you want.

Comment: I edited my question to include links that show the problem.  I have looked at all $_SERVER results, and none of the results give me a path that I can use for this...  Will look at `HTTP_REFERER` again though.

Comment: `HTTP_REFERER` does not help me!  The problem is that I need to get the Long Path and store it in the `$file` php variable so that I can use the player when users browse to my sub-domain....

Comment: Ok, what does the `$path` variable contain. If you echo it out does it have the right path to the mp3 player?

I think you might have to redirect the subdomain to the long URL, rather than just give the content.

Comment: I can't figure out a way to echo it out, cause it is being embedded into the player, so it is used directly within the Flash MP3 Player.  If I echo anything, nothing gets echo'd at all, the only thing that happens is that the MP3 Player loads with no files playing...  And `die` just stops the script from working, no matter what I put into it...

Comment: Also, `var_dump` doesn't seem to have any result also... Here is where I got the code if anyone wants to help me please...  Just trying to integrate it, and have sub-domain problem:http://www.realitysoftware.ca/portfolio/websites/flashmp3player/

Comment: Try using `ob_flush()` before the `var_dump()`.  A lot of the time the scripts will suppress the echoing and so you have to flush the buffer to get it to actually display.

Comment: This does not help, because the flashmp3player.php file is being utilized within the embed tag.  No output gets shown, I can't figure it out either...

Answer (score 0):

If your mp3 file is in some directory like:

```
$path="/music/song.mp3";
```

then to get original path of the file, You can use `realpath()`.

```
$original_path=realpath($path);
```

$original_path contains the direct link of the mp3 file. Hope it helps!

Comment: This is nice, but would be nice informaion...  BUT if there was a URL equivalent of this function, that might actually solve this problem of mine...